Computing composition of affine transformations using semigroup multiplication law
I was trying to understand semidirect product of groups so I looked at the example of the affine group and I would like to know if the reasoning to find the formula for the composition of two affine transformations using the law of semigroup multiplication is correct. I understand from this discussion that the group of translations $T(n)$ is a normal subgroup of the affine transformations $\operatorname{Aff}(n)$ and that the group of linear maps $GL(n)$ is a subgroup which is not normal. Since the only translation such that $T(0)=0$ is the identity and since every affine transformation is the combination of a linear map and a translation, we have a semidirect product $$\operatorname{Aff}(n) = T(n) \rtimes GL(n).$$ Now from wikipedia, the product of two elements satisfies $$(n_1, h_1)(n_2, h_2) = (n_1h_1n_2h_1^{-1} ,h_1h_2)$$ so in our particular case $$(T_v, M)(T_w, N) = (T_vMT_wM^{-1}, MN).$$ Now expanding $$T_vMT_wM^{-1}z = T_v(z+Mw)=z+v+Mw=T_{v+Mw}$$
which is the same as $$T_vMT_wNz=M(Nz+w)+v=MNz+Mz+v=T_{v+Mw}MNz$$
